# Files > 4 are not being uploaded [PHP]

Tags: php

So, just as I was about to launch the site. I've encountered a pretty big bug...
I'm trying to let the user upload files (images) but I've found out that you can't upload more than **4 files**. So, I took the code apart and simplified it. A simple print statement shows the total files uploaded (array elements). And guess what ? It only goes up to 3. After this, the print statement isn't even executed as the `isset($_FILES['files'])` turns out to be **FALSE!**

Here's the **form** which I'm using :

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name='files[]' multiple='multiple'>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here's the **PHP script** that handles the upload :

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        print $key;

        //the uploading process...
    }
}
```

This only prints `$key` upto 3. (0,1,2,3). So that means that files more than 4 aren't even uploaded. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is received file count depends of file sizes ? Do you try to upload smaller files?

Comment: @Psyhos No, it does not depend upon the file size.. At-least not in this prototype which I'm trying to debug. I've checked my php.ini and max file upload size is 64m. AND, WHY did I got a negative vote? This question is legit :(

Comment: Please, check, is there any errors in `$_FILES`: `if(isset($_FILES['files'])) { echo '<pre>' .print_r($_FILES) . '</pre>';}`

Comment: There are no errors... Read the comments of the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the value for `max_file_uploads` in php.ini. It can be increased by simply changing to: `max_file_uploads = 15`.

Comment: It's already set to 20 :) Any other ideas? 
PS : I tested this on another machine and still the same issue.

Comment: @candh Check your browser try different one, and debug in network tab in chrome.

Comment: Checked on Firefox, Chrome... AND on another machine. Lol. This is pretty weird behavior..

Comment: And you're on localhost?

Comment: yep.. I'm on WAMP (localhost)

Comment: WAIT! I JUST tested on a live server and its working! :O

Comment: Any tips to avoid this on localhost ? Or should I email the WAMP team ?

Comment: @candh if `phpinfo()` shows right `max_file_uploads`, then I have no idea. How to fix it.